# Превратить файлы для 3D-принтера в плоскую проекцию с размерами

Tags: 3d, поиск-программ

Имеется относительно плоская головоломка и [файлы для её печати на 3D-принтере](https://www.prusaprinters.org/prints/49163-oleo-10-puzzle/files). У меня нет 3D-принтера, но такое вполне реально вырезать из картона, только надо из соответствующих файлов (расширения `gcode` и `stl`) как-то сделать двумерную проекцию того, что надо вырезать, с возможностью измерить размеры.

[image: Фото головоломки]

`stl` вполне открывается в Paint3D, но до понимания размеров там далеко. Хотя и есть сетка со шкалой, дающая представление о фигуре в целом, измерить расстояние до конкретных вырезов проблематично:

[image: скриншот открытия stl]

Для `gcode` нашёлся [онлайн-вьювер](https://gcode.ws/), который в даёт представление о плоской проекции, и даже позволяет смотреть, как бы эта фигура печаталась (если я правильно понял, что делают ползунки), но возможности измерить размеры не предоставляет. Если с одним файлом ещё можно было бы измерять на скриншоте экрана (хотя так себе способ), то при нескольких файлах есть подозрение, что масштаб окажется разным.

[image: скриншот открытия gcode]

**Что можно использовать для преобразование имеющихся файлов в нечто плоское и пригодное для измерения?**

Comment: stl файлы можно открыть в блендере (https://www.blender.org/) там их конвертнуть в любой подходящий формат.

Answer (score 1):

gcode файл это перемещения головы принтера змейкой по всей поверхности. Там есть строки [G1 - перемещение головы](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/G000-G001.html)

```
G1 X55.991 Y52.623 E0.02355
G1 X194.004 Y52.623 E4.32729
G1 X194.906 Y52.802 E0.02884
```

Выкидываешь координаты где E(подача пластика в печку) меньше нуля и рисуешь програмно по PDFке отрезки.

```
G21 ; set units to millimeters
G90 ; use absolute coordinates
```

Файл сделан в милиметрах и абсолютных координатах

Файл STL состоит из треугольников:

```
  facet normal 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00 -1.000000E+00
    outer loop
      vertex 2.800000E+01 -4.700000E+01 3.000000E+00
      vertex -2.000000E+00 -4.700000E+01 3.000000E+00
      vertex 1.091000E+00 -3.651300E+01 3.000000E+00
    endloop
  endfacet
```

(Текстовый вид можно получить [например вот этой тулсой](https://github.com/cmpolis/convertSTL/blob/master/convertSTL.rb))

Также эти треугольники можно отрисовать поверх PDF и напечатать на принтере результат. В STL файле нет масштаба и единиц измерения.

Линии на PDF можно рисовать через python-fpdf

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()

gcode = open('/home/eri/Загрузки/piece1_015mm_pla_mk3_2h4m.gcode','r')


x,y,e= 0,0,0
x0,y0 = None, None

for line in  gcode.readlines():
    line = line.split()
    if line and line[0] == "G1":
        try:
            for op in line:
                if op[0] == "X":
                    x = float(op[1:])
                elif op[0] == "Y":
                    y = float(op[1:])                
                elif op[0] == "E":
                    e = float(op[1:])
            if e > 0:
                pdf.line(x0,y0,x,y)
            x0,y0 = x,y
        except:
            pass

pdf.output('piece1_015mm_pla_mk3_2h4m.pdf', 'F')
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как тогда фигуры из разных stl-файлов получаются правильных размеров? Или имеется в виду, что единицей является какой-то юнит, зависящий от конкретного принтера? А во что-нибудь более подходящее для замера можно сконвертировать, чтобы наложить сетку и по точке определять координату?

Comment: Там ещё M73 полно и местами M204.

Comment: M204 - ускорение - пофик. M73 - отображение процента напечатанного - пофик

Comment: Юнит завист от значения в программе конверторе.

Comment: @Qwertiy добавил работающий код ;)

Answer (score 1):

В программе solidworks. Размеры наверно в микронах

[image: в микронах]

Comment: Круто, хотя из минусов - прога платная.